# Word VBA- comment marked text range

Tags: vba, ms-word

This is my first post here.  I'm wondering how to return the character range of the text marked by my 4th comment.

So far I have:

Comments(n).Scope. (this is where I can't find what to do next)

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: `MsgBox ActiveDocument.Comments(1).Range.Text` ?

Comment: or `Scope.Text` ....

Comment: Check out [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845295.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Cody, appreciate the response.  This is helpful in obtaining the text that the comment represents.  However, I am also trying to obtain the character numbers of that text.  For example, if my first comment covers characters #180 to #205 of my document, I would like to return 180-205.  And thank you for the MSDN link, it is helpful for other components of my project...still looking for the character solution.

Comment: .Start and .End on the range object?

Comment: Thanks Jbjstam worked perfect.